# Matlab - Sort into deciles each column

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, statistics

Suppose I have a matrix `A [m x 1]`, where m is not necessarily even. I to create a matrix `B also [m x 1]` which tells me the decile of the elements in `A` (i.e. matrix B has numbers from 1 to 10).

I know I can use the function `sort(A)` to get the position of the elements in A and from there I can manually get deciles. Is there another way of doing it?

I think one possibility would be `B = ceil(10 * tiedrank(A) / length(A)` . What do you think? Are there any issues with this?

Also, more generally, if I have a matrix `A [m x n]` and I want to create a matrix `B also [m x n]`, in which each column of B should have the decile of the corresponding column in `A` , is there a way of doing it without a for loop through the columns?

Hope the problem at hand is clear. So far I have been doing it using the sort function and then manually assigning the deciles, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: Clarification: e.g. for `A=1:100`, the `B` would have value `1` in the first 10 elements, 2 in the next 10, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
N = 10;
B = ceil(sum(bsxfun(@le, A(:), A(:).'))*N/numel(A));
```

This counts, for each element, how many elements are less than or equal to it; and then rounds the results to `10` values.

Depending on how you define deciles, you may want to change `@le` to `@lt`, or `ceil` to `floor`. For `numel(A)` multiple of `N`, the above definition gives exactly `numel(A)/N` values in each of the `N` quantiles. For example,

```
>> A = rand(1,8)
A =
    0.4387    0.3816    0.7655    0.7952    0.1869    0.4898    0.4456    0.6463
>> N = 4;
>> B = ceil(sum(bsxfun(@le, A(:), A(:).'))*N/numel(A))
B =
     2     1     4     4     1     3     2     3
```

Comment: Beautiful. Now do this in MATL! +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Good idea! This suits MATL very well

Comment: @rayryeng `itnwY)t!>~si*w/Y]D`. 18 bytes. First input is `A`, second is `N`